# Jenkins Certificate Installation: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: jenkins, certificate

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH - 
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite
```

All I could find online regarding this error is that this may relate to RSA/DSA. I've checked this out and could not find any conflicts so I'm not sure why the error still occurs. I am using keytool to install this certificate on a Jenkins server. How can I resolve this error and install my certificate?

Comment: You are connecting directly to the Jenkins tomcat's, or using a reverse proxy? This error is showed on logs files or on the browser?

Your problem seems that your certificate uses a cipher not allowed on the webserver

Comment: This is the message from the browser. It is not reverse proxy.

Comment: Ok... The problem is between the web server and the browser... Which version of jenkins are you using? Your browser is up to date? Have you tried with other browsers? Have you tried using OpenSSL to check the HTTPS connection?